# How to solve WordPress permalinks issue?

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I've faced a problem with the permalinks structure in WordPress
I need a link that looks like: https://example.com/?lang=en
But WordPress automatically does this link like https://example.com/langen
Who has faced this problem and found a solution?

I've tried several plugins but they dont help me

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you are talking about the permalink of a specific page: WordPress deletes characters from permalinks like ‘?’ and ‘=‘. If you want to achieve this, I would look into editing the .htaccess file. There you can specify that url’s with a certain query string are rewritten to another url.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=en$
RewriteRule (.*) /langen [R=301,L]
```

Add this bit before the bit that WordPress adds to your .htaccess file.